# Velocity statement to add class to last menu item?

Tags: java, velocity

I have this velocity code for a simple menu:

```
<div id="header" class="navstrip">

  #foreach( $navItem in $navItems )
     <a href="$navItem.URL">$navItem.Title</a> |
  #end

</div>
```

I would like to give the last menu link a class of "last". What would the conditional be for that?

Answer (score 9):

Detecting last item is the most buggy spot in Velocity for some reason, I created 3 bug reports about it and even though it says they are solved - it still doesn't work perfectly to my knowledge.

If you are using **Velocity 1.6** and below then there are following options:

1) Using loop tool

```
#foreach( $navItem in $loop.watch($navItems) )
    #if($loop.last) 
        last 
    #end
#end
```

But this doesn't work ([see bug #1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELTOOLS-124))

2) Using internal counter `$velocityCount`:

```
#foreach( $navItem in $navItems)
    #if($velocityCount == $navItems.size()) 
        last 
    #end
#end
```

This works.

In **Velocity 1.7**:

1) You should be able to just use `$foreach.last`:

```
#foreach( $navItem in $navItems)
    #if($foreach.last) 
        last 
    #end
#end
```

But this doesn't work again (see [bug #2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-762) and [bug #3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-763))

2) Comparing current counter to list size:

```
#foreach( $navItem in $navItems)
    #if($foreach.count == $navItems.size()) 
        last 
    #end
#end
```

This works.

Yeah, such simple task and so many troubles.

Comment: Wow Serg, thanks for a comprehensive answer. I didn't find this info anywhere else...

Comment: @Conando Make it output `$foreach.count` or `$velocityCount` in a loop and see what it returns.

Comment: Actually, neither answer seems to work though : )

I have tried both #2 answers above in the following setup:

`#foreach( $navItem in $navItems )
     #if($foreach.count == $navItems.size())   
       <a href="$navItem.URL" class="navstrip last">$navItem.Title</a>  
     #else                                          
       <a href="$navItem.URL" class="navstrip" >$navItem.Title</a>
     #end
  #end`

This always applies 'last'

Comment: Hi Serg - velocityCount outputs 1 - 7 correctly; $foreach.count just echos itself "$foreach.output"

Comment: I should add I working through an unusual interface: using PageLime for a client which uses velocity in the background to process navigation items.

Comment: @Conando If `$velocityCount` outputs correctly then how come it doesn't work? Try to output `$navItems.size()` then as well and see why it doesn't match. `$foreach.count` was introduced in 1.7b1. Are you sure you are using 1.7?

Comment: navItems.size or navItems.size(), just outputs itself also. Weird. I think I give in on Velocity...have to find a different hack...

Comment: Since it's through PageLime, they haven't said which version and haven't heard anything yet on the forums there...

Comment: @Conando I am pretty sure it is 1.6 then is if not less. What is a type of `$navItems`, some `<ArrayList>` I assume? You just need to find a way to get its size.

Comment: This is what works for me Serg -

    #if ($velocityCount == $navItems.Count)

Comment: @Conando ok. $navItems must be some non standard collection, I assumed it implements `<List>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#for ($page in $pages)
 .....
  #if ($velocityHasNext), #end
#end
```

works pretty well.